# how to copy text with mouse when nu and mouse=x is set in neovim

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard, mouse

The only time the mouse does not select the numbers when mouse is set is if mouse is set to v. But you cant copy the text with right click or menu key.

Comment: depends on the terminal, but usually you can mark and copy if you hold down Shift in addition to selecting the text with the mouse

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt this opens a menu, but the copy is grayed out

Comment: well, as I said, this depends on the terminal. Please provide more information